# change value A to B, no matter which column it is in

Tags: sql, sql-server

Single UPDATE working:

```
UPDATE users SET email=@newemail WHERE email=@oldemail
(1 Zeile(n) betroffen)
```

Double UPDATE not working:

```
UPDATE users SET email=@newemail WHERE email=@oldemail, alternateEmail=@newemail WHERE alternateEmail=@oldEmail
Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

How would I do this in a single statement (even if I have N columns to check)?

To clarify: If I have the table

```
email     alternateEmail
a@b.c     d@e.f
d@e.f     a@b.c
```

and I set `@oldemail='a@b.c'`, `@newemail='g@h.i'`, the resulting table should be

```
email     alternateEmail
g@h.i     d@e.f
d@e.f     g@h.i
```

I know I could do it in 2 (or N) statements:

```
UPDATE users SET email=@newemail WHERE email=@oldemail
UPDATE users SET alternateEmail=@newemail WHERE alternateEmail=@oldEmail
```

but could I do it in one statement?

Comment: Generally, it's the sign of a broken data model if you have the same "kind" of data stored in more than one column. A better design would move the emails out into a separate table which can then have as many *rows* as are required and an additional column to indicate, say, the *priority* for each email (such as standard, alternate, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE users SET 
    email = case 
               when email = @oldemail then @newemail 
               else email 
            end,
    alternateEmail = case 
                       when alternateEmail = @oldemail then @newemail 
                       else alternateEmail 
                     end
where 
    email = @oldemail 
    or alternateEmail = @oldemail
```

Comment: Will an update that doesn't actually change the value end up being logged and increase a transaction size? I'm wondering if the query shouldn't also have a WHERE clause to limit the rows the update statement will actually run for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen reasonable note, thanks. Missed  where condition.